# Dates/Calendar in Java

Tags: java, datetime

Does java.util.Calendar supports automatic winter/summer time changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's more up to `java.util.TimeZone` to do that... but yes, in general Java is aware of daylight saving time.

I would personally recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of `java.util.{Date,Calendar}` though - it's a *much* nicer API.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Time zones handled automatically in *java.time*:

```
ZonedDateTime.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Edmonton" ) ).plusMonths( 6 )
```

… results is same time of day, but different offset because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) versus standard time.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The Answer by Jon Skeet is correct, and was correct in its day. But now the old date-time classes such as `Calendar` have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, built into Java 8+. The *java.time* / JSR 310 project was led by the same man who led the *Joda-Time* project, Stephen Colebourne.

Avoid those legacy classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, etc.

## *java.time*

The replacement for `java.util.Calendar` class, or more precisely its common subclass, `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, is `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

The replacement for `java.util.TimeZone` is `java.time.ZoneId` and `java.time.ZoneOffset`.

To answer your question, yes, the *java.time* classes do account for the temporal anomalies introduced by politicians.

These anomalies, these changes in the offset used by time zones, are documented in [*tzdata*](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Each implementation of Java comes with a copy of *tzdata*. You will need to update the *tzdata* file if the rules change for any time zone of interest to you.

```java
ZoneId zEdmonton = ZoneId.of ( "America/Edmonton" );
ZonedDateTime zdtEdmontonNow = ZonedDateTime.now ( zEdmonton );
ZonedDateTime zdtEdmontonInSixMonths = zdtEdmontonNow.plusMonths ( 6 );
```

Be aware that Alberta Canada is using standard time in this example run below. In six months, those Canadians will "Spring ahead" their clocks in the fit of silliness known as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

When adding six months, the `ZonedDateTime` class tries to establish the same time-of-day on the later date. So we see `19:23:10` (7 PM) as the time of day in both outputs, the time-of-day now and the time-of-day then. But 7 PM comes an hour earlier in the summer of 2024 in Alberta. So we see the offset from the temporal meridian of UTC narrow to six hours behind (-06:00) rather than seven hours behind (-07:00).

When run:

```
zdtEdmontonNow.toString() = 2023-12-07T19:23:10.695465-07:00[America/Edmonton]
zdtEdmontonInSixMonths.toString() = 2024-06-07T19:23:10.695465-06:00[America/Edmonton]
```